# SORTING '1 of 20% item' Firebird2.1 SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, firebird2.1

I have a Firebird2.1 table that stores a custom item - a varchar(35) column named 'PARTICULARS' and it is something like this:

```
1 of 20% item
5 of 20% item
3 of 20% item
4 of 20% item
7 of 20% item
2 of 20% item
.
.
.
```

and I wanted to sort them in the natural way like this:

```
1 of 20% item
2 of 20% item
3 of 20% item
4 of 20% item
5 of 20% item
7 of 20% item
.
.
.
```

I have done numerous sql commands like:

```
select * from TABLE order by 1
select * from TABLE order by PARTICULARS asc nulls last
select * from TABLE order by '00000000000000000000000000000000000'+trim(PARTICULARS)(35)
select * cast(PARTICULARS as varchar(35)) from TABLE order by 1
```

But still I get the same table above. I am a newbie vb.net programmer and it had been a couple of days since I started working this stuff. Would someone help me. Thank you in advance.

mikeCoolGuy!

Comment: I would have expected an `ORDER BY` to take care of this. Is the content of your question the real values you are working with?

Comment: I just tested it, and `ORDER BY` should just work correctly here. What is the DDL of the table, including the character set and collation of the column?

Comment: That `ORDER BY 1` you are using means sort on the first column, is `PARTICULARS` actually the first column if you do a `SELECT *`, otherwise just put in an explicit `ORDER BY PARTICULARS`.

Answer (score 1):

> select * from  table_name order by cast (PARTICULARS as int) asc

**You should type cast varchar to int or float to sort.**.

Hope it does good for you.

Comment: I did that but since my record is not entirely integer i get error

Comment: I believe i have to use some sort of 'trim command sql' to solve this, I just don't know how..

Comment: @user2272747: Try this: 
select PARTICULARS from table_name order by case IsNumeric(PARTICULARS) when 1 then Replicate('0', 100 - Len(35)) + PARTICULARS else PARTICULARS end

Comment: Hey thanks for the info but as I've said a while ago - I'm using Firebird2.1 as my database and 'Replicate' does not work on Firebird (as far as I've search http://forums.devshed.com/firebird-sql-development-61/firebird-replication-830836.html) so any ideas ??

Comment: This doesn't work on Firebird (nor on most databases with a more strict interpretation of SQL standards with regard to conversions of datatypes)

Comment: @user2272747 You could try [LPAD](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-lpad.html)

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel Can you help me out in coding?? if it is not much to ask?

Comment: @user2272747 Maybe somewhere in the weekend

Comment: @user2272747 : http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-intfunc-cast.html
Check this example where it seems like it suits u..
select cast(zin as type of dunl20) from zinnen order by 1.
I am Sorry for my last comment as my working enviornment made me to post it.